# ordering/sorting a pulldown box/dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to order/sort a pulldown/dropdown list.

What do I have to add to the following code?

```
public void financeInit()
{
     financeEntities db = new financeEntities();
     ViewData["currencyList"] = db.exchrates.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many things that you should do to this code but for starters try ordering:

```
ViewData["currencyList"] = db.exchrates
    .OrderBy(x => x.SomePropertyYouWnatToOrderBy)
    .ToList();
```

and the other things that you should do with this code:

- use a repository instead of directly invoking a database call inside a controller in order to weaken the coupling between your controllers and data access layer.
- define view models and get rid of ViewData. Then pass a strongly typed view model to the view.